# Enable Button when uri value have data in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am playing audio. i want that when "uri" variable is null btnplay is disabled and when "uri" variable have data btnplay is enable

here is my code. what should i do?

```
fun playmusic(view : View)
    {
        if(uri == null)
        {
            btnPlay.isClickable = false
        }
        else
        {
            btnPlay.isClickable = true
            mp = MediaPlayer()
            if(mp.isPlaying)
            {
                mp.pause()
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow)
            }
            else
            {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,uri)
                mp.start()
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause)
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `btnPlay.isEnabled` property instead of `btnPlay.isClickable`